# ondrag event is not working on the Chromium

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, chromium, xilinx

My code is like this:

```
id="drag1" class="channel" src="test.png" draggable="true" ondrag="drag(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" ondragend="dragend(event)"
```

The `ondragstart` and `ondragend` event work fine.
But `ondrag` event will not be fired.  I don't know why.

Chromium with version 54.0.2810.2 is cross-compiled by xilinx 2019.1.

Comment: Does the same thing work on Chrome? Also please post the relevant code

Comment: Chrome in PC works fine.  I have tried 54.0.2840.59，even the old version 6.0.x.

Comment: Is the drag event associated with the OS or with some flags of the Chromium?